# What is the arp_scroll_position cookie and how to prevent it?

Tags: cookies, web, browser

my web site suddenly started to write a cookie named `arp_scroll_position` in Chrome.
I did not change anything on my application to make this cookie appear, which is why that is very confusing.

In other browsers however this cookie is not set. I just tested Safari, Firefox and even Chrome Canary for that.

I also see this cookie on some other (but not all) websites. So it seems sort of being randomly placed.

I wish to have a cookieless application (no cookie usage warning & respecting the privacy of my users), so this cookie that just pops up in Chrome does counteract that a bit.

So my questions are: Where does this cookie come from? How can I prevent that cookie to be set at all?

Additional info: I use Twitter Bootstrap, but some other sites using bootstrap do not have this cookie.

Answer (score 6):

Old question, but in case someone else stumbles into this:

Maybe you are using a Chrome extension called "[Auto Refresh Plus (arp)](https://github.com/lomholdt/arp)". It sets a cookie with that name, [see source code](https://github.com/lomholdt/arp/blob/36a2b21a956aea50fb2e13451c0d9063a98278ba/js/content_script.js#L25)

Deactivate the extension, delete that cookie in the developer console, and reload the page. Cookie should be gone.